# Xamarin Android - How to use JobInfo.TriggerContentUri when there's no constructor available?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to convert a simple code provided by google for android, allowing me to create a jobservice which triggers when a new media is created ([source](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html#media-broadcasts)).

I can convert almost all without any problem, but it seems impossible to create a new TriggerContentUri, because no constructor exists :

```cs
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, new ComponentName(context, serviceName));
// Look for specific changes to images in the provider.
// !!! Below no constructor exists : new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(...)
builder.AddTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, TriggerContentUriFlags.NotifyForDescendants));
// Also look for general reports of changes in the overall provider.
//builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(MEDIA_URI, 0));
var jobInfo = builder.Build();
```

Do someone has a solution for this kind of problem, or is this simply a bug in the xamarin implementation ?

My solution references Mono.Android 7.1, and targets Android 6.0 at minimum.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, because it is a **bug** in the xamarin implementation.

A bug is opened on their bugzilla platform : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59198

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(Uri uri, int flags)
```

Source:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
Unfortunately, it _should_ be that, but as I mentioned, if it was pure Java Android, but I develop my service with C# Xamarin implementation.
And it doesn't work like this.